# JS - How can I generate a long random number?

Tags: javascript, random, digits, zero-padding

I know that I need to use Math.random() for making random numbers, but today I tried to make a random number between 1 and 9999...(9 repeated 19 times) and my output always ends in 3-5 zeroes. How can I generate more detailed random numbers?

What I've done:

```
const foo = Math.floor(Math.random() * parseInt("9".repeat(19)));
```

Also, I'm pretty sure I know how to do this, but if anyone can tell me, how do I pad zeroes to get to a certain digit count?
(ex. pad(15,4) becomes 0015 because the you need 2 more digits to make it 4 digits long)

Comment: The maximum integer you can represent without loss of precision is `2^53 - 1`, which has 16 digits. In other words, you cannot have an integer value derived from a 19 digit long string without loosing precision. Proof: `9007199254740991 + 1 ` and `9007199254740991 + 2` are both `9007199254740992`. Welcome to the world of floating point values.

Comment: So, what you may want is `Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);` instead.

Comment: [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea is probably to just use a string of random integers (solves padding too):

```js
let foo = '';
for(i=0; i<19; ++i) foo += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are running into Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. The largest exact integral value is 2^53-1, or 9007199254740991.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use numbers encoded as strings.  A loop like this:

```
var desiredMaxLength = 19
var randomNumber = '';
for (var i = 0; i < desiredMaxLength; i++) {
    randomNumber += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

Arthimetic for numbers represented as strings can be donw with the `strint` library found at https://github.com/rauschma/strint.